# Linker error when trying to use LZMA in boost::iostreams from MacPorts

Tags: c++, boost, macports, boost-iostreams

I'm trying to write a function that compresses a data buffer and writes it to a file, but I'm having trouble getting it to build properly.  The code itself is pretty straightforward:

```
void writeToFile(std::string fileName, const char* buf, size_t bufSize) {
    boost::filesystem::ofstream outFile(fileName, std::ios::out | std::ios::binary | std::ios::trunc);

    boost::iostreams::filtering_streambuf<boost::iostreams::output> out;
    out.push(boost::iostreams::lzma_compressor());
    out.push(outFile);

    boost::iostreams::copy(boost::iostreams::basic_array_source<char>(buf, bufSize), out);
}
```

However, when I try to build it, I get a bunch of linking errors:

- Undefined symbol: boost::iostreams::lzma_error::check(int)
- Undefined symbol: boost::iostreams::lzma::stream_end
- Undefined symbol: boost::iostreams::lzma::default_compression
- etc.

I'm already linking to both libboost_iostreams-mt and libboost_system-mt, since if I use bzip2 or zlib equivalents, everything builds just fine.

I currently get boost through MacPorts, and I have version 1.71.  (I updated my ports and ran `sudo port install boost` a few hours ago.)  Running `nm` on my copy of libboost_iostreams-mt.dylib shows symbols related to many other compression algorithms that Boost.Iostreams offers, but the LZMA-related symbols are nowhere to be found.  **What can I do to get a library with the proper symbols I need?**

(Technically, I don't NEED to use LZMA for my purposes here, and I could probably also work around this by grabbing lzma.cpp from [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/libs/iostreams/src/lzma.cpp) and compiling it in with everything else, but I'm still curious as to what a general fix would be.)

**Edit 1:**

In response to n.m.'s comment, I'm building this as a command line tool through Xcode against the .xcconfig file below, so my exact build command is whatever Xcode spits out.

```
HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS = $(inherited) /opt/local/include/
LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS = $(inherited) /opt/local/lib/

OTHER_LDFLAGS = $(inherited) -lboost_iostreams-mt -lboost_system-mt
```

Comment: Please show your exact build command.

Comment: You may have boost configured without lzma.

Comment: I assume the issue is due to the xcode 11 update. Follow this [thread](https://lists.macports.org/pipermail/macports-dev/2019-September/041201.html) from macports mailing lists. Some workarounds have been discussed.